# error: "method does not override or implement a method from a supertype". while creating webview of website

Tags: java, android, overriding

I am new to android and java. I am trying to create a web view of my website with help of a youtube tutorial.
When I compiles it shows the error

> error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

I think error is `public void onbackPressed`

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.govindan.alomaufh;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mywebView.getSettings();
        mywebView.loadUrl("http://app.aloma.in/");
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }
    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onbackPressed() {
        if (mywebView.canGoBack()) {
            mywebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you have such a message is simple.
Change `public void onbackPressed` into `public void onBackPressed`, with an uppercase **B**

Comment: ohh thanks . i am a beginner dosent know any basics. just following some blogs and youtube video. now it is working can you help me to remove app title and url from my app

Comment: done ;) If you're a beginner, don't forget to read or find information from the documentation : https://developer.android.com/